# how to arrange 4 divs horizontally with first 2div of fixed length and the 4the one also fixed length and 3rd one is fluid

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs, out of which I want the first 2 divs to be of fixed width and stick to left of the screen and the 4th div should also be of fixed width and stick to the right of the screen and the 3 rd div should take the space between them.....this should also be the same on the small screen and divs should not go to the next line.

Comment: Hello @Achal please add some code that you tried already, so we can help you according to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use `flexbox`: 
For Each fixed width div add your initial width to CSS.

For the third div add:

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

This will make it stretch to fit the remaining width.

Demo:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.i1 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.i2 {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.i3 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.i4 {
  width: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item i1">Div A</div>
  <div class="item i2">Div B</div>
  <div class="item i3">Div C</div>
  <div class="item i4">Div D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect situation to use **display:grid;**.
You want to have a container (the grid), with the 4 elements inside.
And you want to define the grid with 3 fixed width columns and 1 column that will take the free space, you could something like this:

```css
.container{
 height: 20vh;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 1fr 50px;
 grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

.item{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution also worked for me .thank u